# Trouble Modifying tuples in C++ and getting them to add numeric values together, concatenating string objects, and displaying the remaining objects

Tags: c++, tuples

Hello I asked recently a question about tuples and was helped a lot, the current code is from when I was helped

```
template<class ... Args>
auto sum(tuple<Args...> const& t) {
   double res = 0.0;
   auto addToRes = [&](auto arg){
       if constexpr (is_arithmetic_v<decltype(arg)>) &!
           res += arg;
           
   };
   apply([&](auto&&... args){ (addToRes(args),...); }, t);
   return res;
   
}

template<class ... Args>
auto concat(tuple<Args...> const& t) {
   string res;
   auto addToRes = [&](auto arg){
       if constexpr (is_convertible_v<decltype(arg), string>)
           res += arg;
           
          
   };
   apply([&](auto&&... args){ (addToRes(args),...); }, t);
   return res;
   
}



template<class ... Args>
void test(tuple<Args...> t) {
   cout << sum(t) << "," << concat(t) << endl; 
   cout << tuple_size<decltype(t)>::value;
}

int main(){
   
   test(make_tuple(10, true, "Hello", 2.3f, "World"));
}
```

The code outputs (13.3, "Hello World")

It is taking the Boolean into consideration for arithmetic since its value is 1. Im trying to just sum the available arithmetic in the tuple, concat everything that can be cast to a string and then tally the remaining. So the Desired output should be something like (12.3, "Hello World", 1)

I really appreciate the help, thank you

Comment: `bool` is an arithmetic type. If you don't like this, you need to specifically filter out `bool` with another (condition  in) `if constexpr`.

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::is_same_v`?

Comment: Does `&!res += arg;` really compile?

Answer (score 0):

As your two functions are each almost doing the same thing, and then you want a count of the elements that were not handled by those two functions, it seemed easiest to combine them all into a bigger summarize function that does all the work on a single pass:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<class ... Args>
auto summarize(tuple<Args...> const& t) {
    double num = 0.0;
    std::string str;
    int tally = 0;
    auto combine = [&](auto const & arg){
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr (is_arithmetic_v<T> && 
                      not is_same_v<T, bool> && 
                      not is_same_v<T, char>) {
            num += arg;
        }
        else if constexpr (is_convertible_v<T, string>) {
            str += arg;
        }
        else {
            ++tally;
        }
   };
   apply([&](auto&&... args){ (combine(args),...); }, t);
   return std::tuple(num, str, tally);
}

int main() {
    auto const & [num, str, tally] = summarize(std::tuple(5,"hello", 12, true));
    std::cout << "num=" << num << ", str= `" << str << "', count of other=" << tally << "\n";
}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/z/rzrxK49Tb

Note, I also excluded 'char' type but you might want to go through all the types and decide what you want to include, exclude, or handle specially.

Comment: Thank you very much on the clarification and the help